# VBA/Macro Vs Manual Solver in multiple condition isn't equal

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, solver

I'm trying to use solver to Minimal Cell L3
Condition :

1. Cell F2 = 1
2. Cell H3:I3 >=0

I'm manual solver and recording Macro parallel.
Manual Result => 0.509704119237237
but next time I'm Run The Marco
Macro Result => 0.283145170572955
**(Why? => $H$3:$I$3 > 1)**
It not equal so I go to solver toolbar and print screen Manual Vs Macro condition 1 disappear
but check Macro it have " SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$2", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1" " so I don't understand what is going on.

Correct Answer : 0.509704119237237

Link File here : [Test VBA Solver_2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lj1vxhhcdtbyhi0/Test%20VBA%20Solver_2.xlsb?dl=0)

```
Sub Macro2_Original()

SolverReset

SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$2", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"

SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$3:$I$3", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"

SolverOk SetCell:="$L$3", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$H$3:$I$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    
SolverSolve (True)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question.

Comment: if you can say what is for you the correct result. So i can find where is the problem.